# D3.js Line chart not updating properly when applying the general update pattern

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a project where I try to create a line chart. I have used the general update pattern in order to properly load, update and delete lines on the chart. I have already used this pattern on other charts types(barchart, scatterplot).

But I cannot get the general update pattern to work on my line chart. I have added the three states the line can be in when updating the data: enter, update and exit.

In the enter state the line should transition in from the bottom of the chart. This seems to be working perfectly fine.

The main problem is when I try to update the chart. When the chart switches to a new set of data, each point on the line should transition to its new position. But in my code does not seem to trigger the update part of the code. The line comes from the bottom of the screen instead of transitioning from the previous state.

This is the section of my code where I try to implement the general update pattern on a line chart:

```
      // Update line.
      this.line = this.svg.selectAll(".line").data([data], d => d.key)
      this.line = this.line
        .data([data], d => d.key)
        .join(
          enter => {
            enter
              .append("path")
              .attr("class", "line")
              .merge(this.line)
              .attr("fill", "none")
              .attr("stroke", "#206BF3")
              .attr("stroke-width", 4)
              .attr(
                "d",
                d3
                .line()
                .x(d => {
                  return this.xScale(d.key);
                })
                .y(() => {
                  return this.yScale(0);
                })
              )
              .transition(t)
              .attr(
                "d",
                d3
                .line()
                .x(d => {
                  return this.xScale(d.key);
                })
                .y(d => {
                  return this.yScale(d.value);
                })
              );
          },

          update => {
            update.transition(t).attr(
              "d",
              d3
              .line()
              .x(d => {
                return this.xScale(d.key);
              })
              .y(d => {
                return this.yScale(d.value);
              })
            );
          },

          exit => exit.remove()
        );
```

This is a working snippet of the state my chart is in now:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      data: [
        [{
            key: "Jan",
            value: 5787
          },
          {
            key: "Feb",
            value: 6387
          },
          {
            key: "Mrt",
            value: 7375
          },
          {
            key: "Apr",
            value: 6220
          },
          {
            key: "Mei",
            value: 6214
          },
          {
            key: "Jun",
            value: 5205
          },
          {
            key: "Jul",
            value: 5025
          },
          {
            key: "Aug",
            value: 4267
          },
          {
            key: "Sep",
            value: 6901
          },
          {
            key: "Okt",
            value: 5800
          },
          {
            key: "Nov",
            value: 7414
          },
          {
            key: "Dec",
            value: 6547
          }
        ],
        [{
            key: "Jan",
            value: 2562
          },
          {
            key: "Feb",
            value: 3882
          },
          {
            key: "Mrt",
            value: 2323
          },
          {
            key: "Apr",
            value: 1283
          },
          {
            key: "Mei",
            value: 3526
          },
          {
            key: "Jun",
            value: 4578
          },
          {
            key: "Jul",
            value: 3848
          },
          {
            key: "Aug",
            value: 3564
          },
          {
            key: "Sep",
            value: 2436
          },
          {
            key: "Okt",
            value: 2536
          },
          {
            key: "Nov",
            value: 2733
          },
          {
            key: "Dec",
            value: 3172
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 30
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;

    this.height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    this.svg = d3
      .select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
      .attr(
        "viewBox",
        `0 0 ${width + margin.left + margin.right} ${this.height +
          margin.top +
          margin.bottom}`
      )
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // set the ranges
    this.xScale = d3
      .scalePoint()
      .range([0, width])
      .domain(
        this.data.map(function(d) {
          return d.key;
        })
      )
      .padding(0.5);

    this.yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([this.height, 0]);

    this.yScale.domain([0, 7000]);

    // Draw Axis
    this.xAxis = d3.axisBottom(this.xScale);

    this.xAxisDraw = this.svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${this.height})`);

    this.yAxis = d3
      .axisLeft(this.yScale)
      .tickValues([0, 7000])
      .tickFormat(d => {
        if (d > 1000) {
          d = Math.round(d / 1000);
          d = d + "K";
        }
        return d;
      });

    this.yAxisDraw = this.svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis");

    this.update(this.data[this.index]);
  },
  methods: {
    swapData() {
      if (this.index === 0) this.index = 1;
      else this.index = 0;
      this.update(this.data[this.index]);
    },
    update(data) {
      // Update scales.
      this.xScale.domain(data.map(d => d.key));
      this.yScale.domain([0, 7000]);

      // Set up transition.
      const dur = 1000;
      const t = d3.transition().duration(dur);

      // Update line.
      this.line = this.svg.selectAll(".line").data([data], d => d.key)
      this.line = this.line
        .data([data], d => d.key)
        .join(
          enter => {
            enter
              .append("path")
              .attr("class", "line")
              .merge(this.line)
              .attr("fill", "none")
              .attr("stroke", "#206BF3")
              .attr("stroke-width", 4)
              .attr(
                "d",
                d3
                .line()
                .x(d => {
                  return this.xScale(d.key);
                })
                .y(() => {
                  return this.yScale(0);
                })
              )
              .transition(t)
              .attr(
                "d",
                d3
                .line()
                .x(d => {
                  return this.xScale(d.key);
                })
                .y(d => {
                  return this.yScale(d.value);
                })
              );
          },

          update => {
            update.transition(t).attr(
              "d",
              d3
              .line()
              .x(d => {
                return this.xScale(d.key);
              })
              .y(d => {
                return this.yScale(d.value);
              })
            );
          },

          exit => exit.remove()
        );

      // Update Axes.
      this.yAxis.tickValues([0, 7000]);
      if (data.length > 12) {
        this.xAxis.tickValues(
          data.map((d, i) => {
            if (i % 3 === 0) return d.key;
            else return 0;
          })
        );
      } else {
        this.xAxis.tickValues(
          data.map(d => {
            return d.key;
          })
        );
      }
      this.yAxis.tickValues([0, 7000]);
      this.xAxisDraw.transition(t).call(this.xAxis.scale(this.xScale));
      this.yAxisDraw.transition(t).call(this.yAxis.scale(this.yScale));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="swapData">Swap</button>
  <div id="my_dataviz" class="flex justify-center"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only need to remove the merge from the update section.

The join is doing a merge automatically. When you add the merge in the update you are in fact merging the enter part with the update. So when you run the update, there is nothing left to do

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      data: [
        [{
            key: "Jan",
            value: 5787
          },
          {
            key: "Feb",
            value: 6387
          },
          {
            key: "Mrt",
            value: 7375
          },
          {
            key: "Apr",
            value: 6220
          },
          {
            key: "Mei",
            value: 6214
          },
          {
            key: "Jun",
            value: 5205
          },
          {
            key: "Jul",
            value: 5025
          },
          {
            key: "Aug",
            value: 4267
          },
          {
            key: "Sep",
            value: 6901
          },
          {
            key: "Okt",
            value: 5800
          },
          {
            key: "Nov",
            value: 7414
          },
          {
            key: "Dec",
            value: 6547
          }
        ],
        [{
            key: "Jan",
            value: 2562
          },
          {
            key: "Feb",
            value: 3882
          },
          {
            key: "Mrt",
            value: 2323
          },
          {
            key: "Apr",
            value: 1283
          },
          {
            key: "Mei",
            value: 3526
          },
          {
            key: "Jun",
            value: 4578
          },
          {
            key: "Jul",
            value: 3848
          },
          {
            key: "Aug",
            value: 3564
          },
          {
            key: "Sep",
            value: 2436
          },
          {
            key: "Okt",
            value: 2536
          },
          {
            key: "Nov",
            value: 2733
          },
          {
            key: "Dec",
            value: 3172
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 30
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;

    this.height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    this.svg = d3
      .select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
      .attr(
        "viewBox",
        `0 0 ${width + margin.left + margin.right} ${this.height +
          margin.top +
          margin.bottom}`
      )
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // set the ranges
    this.xScale = d3
      .scalePoint()
      .range([0, width])
      .domain(
        this.data.map(function(d) {
          return d.key;
        })
      )
      .padding(0.5);

    this.yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([this.height, 0]);

    this.yScale.domain([0, 7000]);

    // Draw Axis
    this.xAxis = d3.axisBottom(this.xScale);

    this.xAxisDraw = this.svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${this.height})`);

    this.yAxis = d3
      .axisLeft(this.yScale)
      .tickValues([0, 7000])
      .tickFormat(d => {
        if (d > 1000) {
          d = Math.round(d / 1000);
          d = d + "K";
        }
        return d;
      });

    this.yAxisDraw = this.svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis");

    this.update(this.data[this.index]);
  },
  methods: {
    swapData() {
      if (this.index === 0) this.index = 1;
      else this.index = 0;
      this.update(this.data[this.index]);
    },
    update(data) {
      // Update scales.
      this.xScale.domain(data.map(d => d.key));
      this.yScale.domain([0, 7000]);

      // Set up transition.
      const dur = 1000;
      const t = d3.transition().duration(dur);

      // Update line.
      this.line = this.svg.selectAll(".line").data([data], d => d.key)
      this.line = this.line
        .data([data], d => d.key)
        .join(
          enter => {
            enter
              .append("path")
              .attr("class", "line")
              .attr("fill", "none")
              .attr("stroke", "#206BF3")
              .attr("stroke-width", 4)
              .attr(
                "d",
                d3
                .line()
                .x(d => {
                  return this.xScale(d.key);
                })
                .y(() => {
                  return this.yScale(0);
                })
              )
              .transition(t)
              .attr(
                "d",
                d3
                .line()
                .x(d => {
                  return this.xScale(d.key);
                })
                .y(d => {
                  return this.yScale(d.value);
                })
              );
          },

          update => {
            update.transition(t).attr(
              "d",
              d3
              .line()
              .x(d => {
                return this.xScale(d.key);
              })
              .y(d => {
                return this.yScale(d.value);
              })
            );
          },

          exit => exit.remove()
        );

      // Update Axes.
      this.yAxis.tickValues([0, 7000]);
      if (data.length > 12) {
        this.xAxis.tickValues(
          data.map((d, i) => {
            if (i % 3 === 0) return d.key;
            else return 0;
          })
        );
      } else {
        this.xAxis.tickValues(
          data.map(d => {
            return d.key;
          })
        );
      }
      this.yAxis.tickValues([0, 7000]);
      this.xAxisDraw.transition(t).call(this.xAxis.scale(this.xScale));
      this.yAxisDraw.transition(t).call(this.yAxis.scale(this.yScale));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="swapData">Swap</button>
  <div id="my_dataviz" class="flex justify-center"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This fixed my problem! But don't you mean "only need to remove the merge from the enter section." instead of "only need to remove the merge from the update section." ?